# Can classes be nested in regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match string like `12af-23f4-123d-`.
Although it is possible to use `[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-`
Can I use nested format like `[[0-9a-f]{4}\-]{3}` ?

Comment: `([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3}` so ?

Comment: Straight brackets `[]` are a character class; parens `()` are used for grouping which gives you the ability to "nest" expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your original regex:

```
[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-
```

can be simplified in

```
([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3}
```

or

```
(([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3})
```

depending on the fact that you want to use the whole match as a whole or not (e.g. backreference,...).

**Tested on regex101**:

https://regex101.com/r/gLSu92/1

https://regex101.com/r/gLSu92/2